# Entity Framework - adding new column to view generates null pointer exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a working project, but when I try to insert a new column into a view in entity framework as follows :
The Mapper class of view contains :

```
namespace DBRefresh.Models.Mapping
{
public class v_Report_HIVE_Roadmap_AnalyticsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<v_Report_HIVE_Roadmap_Analytics>
{
  public v_Report_HIVE_Roadmap_AnalyticsMap()
  {
   // Primary Key
   this.HasKey(t => new { t.Solution_ID_and_Name, t.Viz_Status, t.t_f, t.Updated_MR, 
   t.Governance_Team, t.Tied_to_a_Heavyweight_Solution, t.Solution_Type, t.Is_Dup_,t.ROW_NUM });
   this.Property(t => t.ROW_NUM).IsRequired();
   //other properties defined
   //table column and mapping
   this.Property(t => t.ROW_NUM).HasColumnName("ROW_NUM");
  }
 }
}
```

The Model Class has the following:

```
namespace DBRefresh.Models
{
public partial class v_Report_HIVE_Roadmap_Analytics
{
    public long Row_NUM{ get; set; }
}
}
```

I get a Null Pointer exception when I try to read data from the db. The data is read through various controllers so cannot directly write here, but they all work fine until I add this new column. On adding this column which I have made as a primary key in my view, I get the null pointer exception on the very first table that my application reads.

Database structure for the view is :

```
SELECT *, ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Industry),-1) as ROW_NUM
FROM (
Select ....)
```

The view contains this column as ROW_NUM(bigint,not null)

Trying to figure out the cause for days, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please, edit the question and add copy and paste the exact exception. is it null pointer or null reference?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the model folder select the `model` > `right click` > `select update model from database` > refresh > finish

I hope this helps.